# How it's allowed to access instance method by class name?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In VB.NET, I can have multiple forms and show one from the another by using the following code:

```vb
Form2.Show() ' Form2 is the class name itself!! not an instance..
```

How it that allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Your project uses a `Forms` object in a namespace called `My`. In there, Visual Basic creates default instances of the forms:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/development-with-my/default-object-instances-provided-by-my-forms-and-my-webservices

This seems to be happening somewhere behind the scenes. I have not been able to locate a file in my project where this is happening, but I see `My.Forms` being used in my executable.